# Meteor 1.6 mongo find UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning and limiting find on large collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, es6-promise, unhandled-exception

I am running a query on a large collection (~1.000.000 docs) to get the latest documents.

My function is quite simple:

```js
Meteor.methods({
    getLatest:function() {
        return collection.find({}, {limit: 30, sort:{createdAt:-1});
    },
});
```

which resulted in the following error:

```
(STDERR) (node:15450) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
(STDERR) (node:15450) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried the following other queries:

```js
 collection.find({}, {limit: 30, hint:{$natural:-1});
 collection.find({}, {limit: 30});
```

which resulted in the same error.

When logging the `cursor.count()` inside the method I get the total amount of documents of the collection. This made me think if there is an issue with the `limit`?

When just calling the query and returning something else, the error does not occur:

```js
Meteor.methods({
    getLatest:function() {
        const cursor=  collection.find({}, {limit: 30, sort:{createdAt:-1});
        console.log(cursor.count()); // ~1.000.000
        return []; // does not trigger the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
    },
});
```

Before opening an issue on their project page, I would like to know if someone experienced this, too or found a solution to that.

Comment: So where's your `.catch()` as there is no catch here! and you sort of needs those for promises even if meteor kind of hides it. The likely error error is the *"Sort exceeded memory limit"* when you actually attempt to trap the error and report it. The solution to that is to add an index, which your collection is likely missing.

Comment: Regular [`try..catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) blocks can generally be used with most meteor methods. And where it is in fact a sort memory limit, [see the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#restrictions) *"When unable to obtain the sort order from an index, MongoDB will sort the results in memory, which requires that the result set being sorted is less than 32 megabyte"*. Add an index on `createdAt`

Comment: He doesn't have a `try` block so where would he put a `catch`? The catch has got to be missing from the Meteor-MongoDB code. Checking that there's an index on `createdAt` is definitely a good tip though.

Comment: Add `process.on('unhandledRejection', r => console.log(r));` to your server entry point and it will give you a stack trace to help pinpoint where it's happening. 
Is the correct data still making it to the client?

Comment: @MichelFloyd `try { return collection.find({},{limit: 30, sort:{createdAt:-1}); } catch(e) { console.log(e) }` is essentially the point of what I am saying. And it's perfectly valid for Meteor, and in fact recommended. As stated then the exception which can then be trapped and reported is most probably due to no index on the sorted field, but putting the block there will at least trap the actual error and allow it to be addressed. If you are not trapping exceptions in your code, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: ok - the way you wrote it originally was a bit unclear. Also I was typing my comment at the same time you were typing your second one so race condition...